# How to remove duplicate entries within a column row?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame, df:

```
a <- c("ID1","ID2","ID3")
b <- c("happy;sad","happy;happy","happy;sad;sad;sad")
c <- c("I","II","I")
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)

    a                 b  c
1 ID1         happy;sad  I
2 ID2       happy;happy II
3 ID3 happy;sad;sad;sad  I
```

In column b, there are some duplicates, for example - happy is listed twice in df[2,2], and sad is listed three times in df[3,2].  How do I edit df$b so that it removes duplicate entries and looks like this:

```
    a                 b  c
1 ID1         happy;sad  I
2 ID2             happy II
3 ID3         happy;sad  I
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split, unique, then paste it back again:

```
df$b <- sapply(as.character(df$b), function(i){
  paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(i, ";"))), collapse = ";")
})
#     a         b  c
# 1 ID1 happy;sad  I
# 2 ID2     happy II
# 3 ID3 happy;sad  I
```

Comment: Would you please help me how to do this in python?